# Waiting for a mousepress before proceeding

Tags: python, events, pygame, wait

Yo,
so I'm trying to work on a very simple game, essentially you just have a window and whenever you press once the pygame.mouse.get_pos() data is stored.
The problem I have is waiting for another mouse click so I can store more mouse position data so I can eventually draw a rectangle/square between the 2 mouse clicks.
code:

```
import sys
import pygame as pg
import time
title = "draw rect thign"
running = True
pg.display.init()
surface = pg.display.set_mode(size=(400, 200))
color = (255,0,0)
pg.display.set_caption(title)

while running:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key== pg.K_q:
                pg.display.quit()
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos1 = pg.mouse.get_pos()
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pos2 = pg.mouse.get_pos()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, it is enough to create a list and add coordinates there with each mouse click. Don't forget to clear the list for the next round of the game.

```
import sys
import pygame as pg
import time
title = "draw rect thign"
running = True
pg.display.init()
surface = pg.display.set_mode(size=(400, 200))
color = (255,0,0)
pg.display.set_caption(title)
angles = []

while running:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key== pg.K_q:
                pg.display.quit()
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
            angles.append(pos)
            print(angles)
```